# how to inject events into proper hour cells in React Fullcallendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

How do I inject event into proper cell in week view when I add the event it appears only in all day tab but it's not being displayed on a proper hour field, also I can not find arguments in hooks that would allow mapping hour to proper cell, eventDataTransform hook fires on every update but all i can do is set proper format for Event object, and still I don't know how to map this object to find its way to proper hour cell in week view

```
import React from "react";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import { Button, DateButton, Heading } from "../../../../components";
import FullCalendar, { formatDate } from "@fullcalendar/react"; // must go before plugins
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid"; // a plugin!
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";

function renderEventContent(eventInfo) {
    return (
        <div className="bg-primary">
            <b>{eventInfo.title}</b>
        </div>
    );
}

export const DateWidget = ({
    selectedDays,
    handleDayClick,
    disabledDays,
    setTime,
    clearHours,
    completeProcess,
    lessons
}) => {
    function validateEvent(event) {
        return new Date(event) instanceof Date ? event : false;
    }
    function parseDate(date) {
        if (!validateEvent(date)) {
            console.error(`Date: ${date} is not a valid date`);
            return;
        }
        return format(new Date(date), "yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
    const hoursDisabled = selectedDays.length === 0;
    const callendarEvents = lessons.map(({ from, to }) => {
        from = from && format(new Date(from), "yyyy-MM-ddTmm:ss");
        to = to && format(new Date(to), "yyyy-MM-ddTmm:ss");
        return {
            from,
            to,
            title: "event"
        };
    });

    return (
        <div className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <Heading variant="h5" bsClasses="text-medium-grey mb-0">
                Wybierz datę rozpoczecia zajęć
            </Heading>
            <div
                className={`d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center w-75 ${
                    hoursDisabled ? "disable-all" : ""
                }`}
            >
                <strong className="justify-self-center">Godzina </strong>{" "}
                <div className="justify-self-center my-auto">
                    <DateButton
                        getValues={setTime}
                        resetSignal={clearHours}
                        timer
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <FullCalendar
                headerToolbar={{
                    left: "prev,next today",
                    center: "title",
                    right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay"
                }}
                plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                initialView="dayGridMonth"
                eventContent={renderEventContent}
                eventMinHeight={10}
                events={lessons}
                initialEvents={callendarEvents}
                eventAdd={evt => console.log(evt)}
                eventColor={"#378006"}
                themeSystem="bootstrap"
                allDaySlot={true}
                editable={true}
                slotLaneDidMount={hey => {
                    console.log(hey);
                    return <div>eloo</div>;
                }}
                slotLaneClassNames={hey => {
                    console.log("names", hey);
                    return <div>eloo</div>;
                }}
                firstDay={1}
                eventChange={args => {
                    console.log("hshsh", args);
                }}
            />
            <div className="col-6 col-md-12 mt-3">
                <Button onClick={completeProcess}>Potwierdź wybór</Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Thanks

Comment: `when I add the event it appears only in all day tab`...as per the documentation this will happen only when you don't specify a valid start time for the event (just a date), or if you specifically set the event's `allDay` property to true. So I would guess you didn't supply a time for your event, however you haven't given any examples of the event data.

Comment: I would say though, just from observation, that `yyyy-MM-ddTmm:ss` as a datetime format isn't going to produce a valid time - the hours are missing.